# Regex to replace all occurences of space with plus sign within the href attribute in mod_substitute

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Here's my problem. I want to change all the occurrence of blank spaces in the href attribute of the response HTML to the plus (+) sign.

```
href="example.com/sites/site-name/index.page?path=categotry1/category2/sub category1/file.xml"
```

should get change to:

```
href="example.com/sites/site-name/index.page?path=categotry1/category2/sub+category1/file.xml"
```

I am using apache mod_substitute.

Thanks

Comment: Try `Substitute s/ +(?=[^<]*>[^<>]*<\/a>)/+/ni`.

Comment: @stribizhev it's giving me an error "Substitute takes one argument, Pattern to filter the response content (s/foo/bar/[inf])".

Comment: @stribizhev I tried it but getting error "Substitute takes one argument, Pattern to filter the response content (s/foo/bar/[inf])". Changed delimiter to pipe '|' but no change in the response.

Comment: @stribizhev I tried it removing 'n' flag and it worked more then required. It replaces the space between anchor tag and href as well, something like <a+href=... Any further help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't the most performant way to achieve this, but will work.

```
var reg = /(<a[^>]*href\=\"[^\"]*) (\")/g;
while(myHtml.test(reg)){
   myHtml = myHtml.replace(reg,'$1' + '+' + '$2');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the provided regex is not matching the anchor tag. Instead I tried (<a[^>]*href="[^"]*) ([^"]*") which is replacing last occurred space only. Also I have to use this regex in apache mod_substitute where i cant iterate it

Comment: Thats why you have to put it in a loop.

Comment: Maybe insteaf of myhtml.test use myhtml.search(reg)! = -1. Ive had problems with the 'test' method before.

Comment: How can we put loop in mod_substitute?